# Export Gridview Data to PDF with one of the image column

Tags: c#, itext, aspxgridview

I am using itext dll to export gridview data to pdf. But it has one column as image whose URL is picked from database dynamically. On exporting this column, the path is exported instead of the image. How can i download the image on the fly (Like using Web Client, i used it for Export to Excel) so that the column after exported to PDF show up image instead of path.

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in itextsharp ddl you could use full path of image than you can crate pdf file.
your image file path must be full like.

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/images/logo.png
```

or use replcae your image path than you'll create pdf.